# How can I get the declared type of a variable instead of the real type?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, polymorphism

I have a superclass array of pointers in my main function. When I try to append objects of its child classes, can I get to access the typeid of the child classes instead of the parent class declared before?

```
#include <iostream>

class Quadruped {};
class Equine : public Quadruped {};
class Horse : public Equine {};
class Zebra : public Equine {};

int main(){
    constexpr size_t num=4;
    Quadruped* my_things[num];
    my_things[0] = new Horse;
    my_things[1] = new Horse;
    my_things[2] = new Zebra;
    my_things[3] = new Zebra;
    
    std::cout << typeid(my_things[3]).name() << std::endl;  // Quadruped
    std::cout << typeid(*my_things[3]).name() << std::endl; // Quadruped
};
```

I tried to use the typeid method but it's printing out Quadruped even I dereferenced it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: May I ask for what purpose are you going to use `typeid` for?  Also, [as you can see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb1cabe4f48066da), the results are different than what you are observing.

Comment: This example leaks memory like a sieve.

Comment: You *are* getting the declared type – `my_things` is an array of `Quadruped*`. What you're looking for is the (runtime) type of an object rather than a variable.